# Create a CSS tag over a score card in div

Tags: css

I want to create a Tag as shown below:

[image: CSS Tag]

I don't know how to position it perfectly so that it aligns at the edge.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="project-card">
      <div class="achievement-label">Winner</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.project-card {
  height: 350px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.achievement-label {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0.3rem 3rem;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(5rem);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 75% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Here's the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-cloud-0km40?file=/styles.css:0-295

Comment: read the duplicate for a generic solution without trial & error

Comment: i added an answer with 2 approach , with and without clip-path (also shape-outside) in the duplicate at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128872/how-can-i-make-a-45-degree-responsive-ribbon-with-folded-corner/69235474#69235474

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.project-card {
  height: 350px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.achievement-label {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0.3rem 3rem;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(5rem);
  /* clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 75% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%); */
  left: -30%;
  top: -8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-card">
<div class="achievement-label">hello hi</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your inputs, I was wondering if there's a perfect way to do the same or we need to make hit and trials until we find a solution like in your case.

Comment: @ShivamSahil to avoid trials, you can use offset coordonates and transform-origin . translate should then not be a need anymore , let it go off the box ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128872/how-can-i-make-a-45-degree-responsive-ribbon-with-folded-corner/69235474#69235474

Answer (score 1):

```css
.project-card {
  height: 350px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.achievement-label {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0.3rem 3rem;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(5rem);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 75% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  top: -10%;
    left: -31%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="project-card">
      <div class="achievement-label">Winner</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your inputs, I was wondering if there's a perfect way to do the same or we need to make hit and trials until we find a solution like in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Not pixel-perfect, but closer.

```css
.project-card {
  height: 350px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.achievement-label {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0.3rem 3rem;
  transform: rotateZ( -45deg) translateY(-5px) translateX(-40px);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 80% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="project-card">
    <div class="achievement-label">Winner</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your inputs, I was wondering if there's a perfect way to do the same or we need to make hit and trials until we find a solution like in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.project-card {
  height: 350px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: -1px;
}
.achievement-label {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0.3rem 3rem;
  transform: rotateZ(
-45deg) translate(-2.5rem,-.5rem);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="project-card">
      <div class="achievement-label">Winner</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Shivam Sahil here is best match your answer

```css
  .project-card {
      height: 350px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: blue;
      position: relative;
    }
    .achievement-label {
      position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0.3em 8rem;
     
    transform: rotateZ(-47deg) translateY(0rem) translateX(-6rem);
    clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 75% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
      }
```

```html
 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <title>Static Template</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="project-card">
          <div class="achievement-label">Winner</div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: THe one that you shared is size-dependent and distorts on the size, you're free to tweak my properties but I want a solution that is responsive and unaffected of browser window