# How can I position a ribbon-style 'Sold' banner across a corner of a Woocommerce Product?

Tags: css, wordpress

I wish to add a 'Sold' Product banner to Woocommerce which looks like this:

[image: tyoe of banner, which overlaps product image]

When I add the following code to the functions.php file and the style.css file, the banner appears alongside the image rather than on top of it:

[image]

(I have reverted to using simple text on a background rather than the intended image.) I think if I can just cause the 'Now Sold' text to overlap the image - using `right: 100px;` or `margin-right: 100px;` or some such, then actually using an image instead of the text will be straightforward, as the content between the span brackets can be changed to `<img src="xyz"...` which I have already tried and which works except with the same problem of the output appearing after the image.

(functions.php)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', function() {
   global $product;
   if ( !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
       echo '<span class="now_sold">Now Sold</span>';
   }
});
```

(style.css)

```
.now_sold {
    background: #000080;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

[image]

This is not a question about creating elements in CSS or about different types of banner, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128872/how-can-i-make-a-45-degree-responsive-ribbon-with-folded-corner) but about how to hook into the wordpress-woocommerce API so that any solution will work across different screen formats/sizes/orientations etc as dos the rest of wordpresswoocommerce generally. For that I don't know whether I need relative or absolute css classes, pixels (unlikely) or percentages or elements etc etc etc. Perhaps here is a simple fix using the default wp-content files to avoid all the hit-and-miss css tweaks?

Also, this is the single product page, I would also like the sold banner to display on the Shop home page/category pages, if that means I need to add any code in different locations.

Comment: check this: https://css-generators.com/ribbon-shapes/ and this: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/css-shapes-the-ribbon

Comment: Nice link, but the ribbons change position relative to the product image as I resize the screen. Also appears the positioning is difficult to pinpoint using percentages, which I think I would need to use. This question really aims to find out if anyone knows how to hook into the woocommerce output so that I can attach a banner at the same point regardless of viewport size etc.